# No Main Maifest attribute Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have read all the other threads about this problem and applied all the solutions I could find. Nothing helped. When I run the gradle.build task I get a .jar file. But when running the file I get `no main manifest attribute, in DiscordBotJDA-1.0.jar`
Can annyone provide help?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my gradle.buidl file:

```
/*
 * This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
 * by 'Timbo' at '7/13/16 2:08 PM' with Gradle 2.9
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'start.StartUp'
version = '1.0'


task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'MCI_Bot',  
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'start.StartUp'
            manifest.attributes("Main-Class": 'start.startUp')
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'

    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:2.1.3_327'


    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am using eclipse in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Were you expecting that your "fatJar" task would be doing that?  Just defining the task doesn't put it into the task execution tree.  You have to either run the task directly, or specify a task dependency relationship including your task.  For instance, saying that another task depends on it.

You might be better off just specifying a "jar" configuration block, which will configure the already existing "jar" task, which already has proper dependency relationships defined.

Read the [User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) for examples of configuring the "jar" task.

It might be more convenient to download the Gradle distribution, which provides the PDF of the User Guide, which might be easier to search.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the link to the user guide.